# Conditional NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have two currency values: £2.60 and £22,000. Both are stored as `NSDecimalNumber` in Core Data. I create a string from them using the following:

```
    // The app will be GB only, which is the reason locale is set to en_GB
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale: locale];
    [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    // job is a Core Data entity, value1 and value2 or NSDecimalNumbers
    NSString *value1 = [formatter stringFromNumber: [job value1]]; // 2.60
    NSString *value2 = [formatter stringFromNumber: [job value2]];    // 22000
    NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@", value1, value2];
```

This as a whole works ok, but `testString` prints as £2.60 and £22,000.00.

What would be the best way implement `[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits: 0];` for the largeValue only?

Comment: I've just realised that I have another attribute in my Entity that I can use for this switching, so I'll do that. I'm still open for answers if theres an appropriate way to handle this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on your formatting requirements, but I think a good heuristic would be to chop off the decimal digits when the number shows a thousands separator:

```
if ([[job value2] doubleValue] >= 1000.0) {
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits: 0];
}
```

Comment: Yes I think this is a perfectly acceptable situation. Thanks!